# Map List of tuples in Scala

Tags: scala

I am getting compile error when trying to map list of tuples. I have a method which return `Future[List[(String, String)]]` and I need to use those two set of String value to make a call to another method

```
def myHelper(): Future[List[(String, String)]] = { ... }

def myWork() = {
  myHelper() map {
    case(firstVal, secondVal) => otherWork(firstVal, secondVal)
  }
}
```

Error I am getting is

```
found: (T1, T2)
required: List[(String, String)]
```

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**
hmm .... I wasn't clear about my question. `otherWork` expect list of all result

```
def otherWork(firstVals: List[String], secondVals: List[Strong]) = { ... }
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Moreover, what `otherWork` return type is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's implement the `myWork` function as:

```scala
def myWork = myHelper.map {
  helper => (otherWork _).tupled(helper.unzip)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want to do.

Call `otherWork` on every tuple?

```
def myWork() = {
    myHelper().map(_.map {
        case (firstVal, secondVal) => otherWork(firstVal, secondVal)
    })
}
```

If `otherWork: (String, String) => T`, then `myWork: () => Future[List[T]]`.

If `otherWork: (String, String) => Future[T]` and you want to run them all and collect the results, then you can use something like

```
def myWork() = {
    myHelper() flatMap { list => Future.sequence(
        list map { case (firstVal, secondVal) =>
            otherWork(firstVal, secondVal)
        })
    }
}
```

---

With the question clarification, you want `unzip`.

```
def myWork() = {
    myHelper() map { list =>
        list.unzip match {
            case (firstVals, secondVals) => otherWork(firstVals, secondVals)
        }
    }
}
```

Federico Pellegatta's answer has a shorter form of writing this.

Comment: Updated my question